# php email are sending to gmail but not to outlook or rediffmail

Tags: php, email, outlook

I am facing an issue in php email. I am sending multiple attachments in email and it is working fine with gmail but i am not able to receive email in outlook or in rediffmail

My email code:

```
$header = "From: Futureshirts <designImages@futureshirts.com>\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: noreply@futureshirts.com\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\n\n";
    $emessage= "--".$uid."\n";
    // attachments
    foreach ($imgArr as $key => $file) {
        $content = file_get_contents($file);
        $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
        $fileToExp = $file;
        $value = explode("/", $fileToExp);
        $fileName = strtolower(array_pop($value));   //Line 32
        $emessage.= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
        $emessage.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
        $emessage .= $message."\n\n";
        $emessage.= "--".$uid."\n";
        $emessage .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$fileName."\"\n";
        $emessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
        $emessage .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$fileName."\"\n\n";
        $emessage .= $content."\n\n";
        $emessage .= "--".$uid."--";
        //unlink($file);
    }
    //SEND Mail
     mail($mailto, $subject, $emessage, $header);
```

Comment: did you look in the spam boxes?

Comment: Yes, but did not receiving any email whereas gmail inbox is receiving

Comment: then look at YOUR mail server's log. PHP's job is the equivalent of walking an envelope down to the street corner and dropping it into the mailbox. That's it. Once the letter's in the box, php's job is done, it reports success. If the mailbox is destroyed by a drunk driver, or the postal sorting machines shred the letter, that's not PHP's problem. So... go look at your mail server's logs (aka the postal service)

Comment: ok, thanks for the help

Comment: @MarcB You haven't used that one in a long time. Time for another "blitz".